# Proof norms are equivalent using the following condition

Tags: real-analysis

My question is to show that

> Two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$,  $\|\cdot \|_2$ on a normed vector space $X$ are equivalent if "sequences $\{x_k\}$ converges in $\|\cdot\|_1$ i.f.f. it converges in norm 2 $\|\cdot \|_2$".

I have no idea about this question. Can we just take sequence like
$$
\{\frac{1}{k}\frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|_1}\}
$$

Note that
$$
\|\frac{1}{n}\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_1}\|_1=\frac{1}{n}\to 0
$$
Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $N>0$ so that $n>N$,
$$
\|\frac{1}{n}\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_1}\|_2=\frac{1}{n}\frac{}{}<\epsilon
$$

Hence, $\|x_n\|_2\le n\epsilon \|x_n\|_1$

Does it work? Also, can we use that the limit are both zero for these two different norm? Or they could be have different limit point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the linked question, we can proceed by contraposition : i.e. we assume that $\|\cdot\|_1 $ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are *not* equivalent, and we will prove that, necessarily, there exists a sequence $(y_k)_{k\ge1}\subset X$ which converges in $\|\cdot\|_2$ but not in $\|\cdot\|_1$.

By assumption, the two norms are not equivalent, hence for any positive integer $k$, there exists $x_k\in X$ such that
$$\|x_k\|_1 > k^2\|x_k\|_2 \tag1$$

This way we can thus define a sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge1}$ such that property $(1)$ holds for all $k$.

Now define for all $k\ge 1$ the sequence $$y_k := \frac1k \frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|_2}$$
As you noticed, we have $\|y_k\|_2\to 0 $ hence $y_k$ converges to $0$ in $\|\cdot\|_2$, but by $(1)$ we have
$$\|y_k\|_1 = \frac1k \frac{\left\|x_k\right\|_1}{\|x_k\|_2} > k $$
Hence $\|y_k\|_1$ diverges to infinity, while $\|y_k\|_2$ converges to $0$, which completes the proof by contraposition.

Comment: Thank you! But can we prove it without contraposition?

Comment: You're welcome ! A proof by contradiction is also possible by pretty much following this exact same argument, but for a direct proof I can't think of one right now...